# stream video from pi cam to unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, vuforia

I am using a raspberry pi and pi cam to stream video from my pi to my PC. I've gotten this to work using gstreamer on the pi and the PC, but now i want to use the stream in a Unity augmented reality project.

Here's the code running on the pi:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
raspivid -n -t 0 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 6000000 -o - |  gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=***YOUR_PC_IP*** port=5000
```

In the Unity app i am using Vuforia for augmented reality.
I want to use a pi for the video so that the webcam can be portable.

Any ideas on how to get the stream in Unity C# from the pi?

Comment: Have you looked into RaspberryCam: https://nuget.org/packages/RaspberryCam

Comment: @gmiley looking at it and it seems that is more so for programming using the pi's hardware and pins using mono or windows iot core instead of what im looking

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to stream Pi's camera to Unity in this way, with below solution in two parts.

**Part 1. Raspberry Pi Setup:** install StereoPi OS and run below commands.

```
//1. Connect to your StereoPi via ssh
ssh root@192.168.xx.xx
Pwd: root
 
//2. Stop Default Stream
/opt/StereoPi/stop.sh
 
//3. Start StereoPi stream, either in UDP or TCP
//where 192.168.1.10 3001 is the IP and port of your target device(receiver)
//command for UDP Stream
raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 30 -3d sbs -cd MJPEG -o - | nc 192.168.1.10 3001 -u

//command for TCP Stream
raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 30 -3d sbs -cd MJPEG -o - | nc 192.168.1.10 3001
```

**Part 2. Unity Setup:** import [FMETP STREAM](https://frozenmist.com/docs/apis/fmetp-stream/stereopi-example/) input your project, and add component "FMNetworkmanager.cs", Select network type as StereoPi. The detailed & the latest guide can refer to their [documentation page](https://frozenmist.com/docs/apis/fmetp-stream/stereopi-example/).